# How to adress a attribute created by setattr()?

Tags: python, class, oop, micropython

I want to create a Micropython-Class for an LED-Strip. When initializing, the class can be called with any number of color=Pin pairs.
So my idea was to call `def __init__(self, **kwargs)` and then use:

```
for color, pin in kwargs.items():
    setattr(self, color, PWM(Pin(pin)))
```

I want to refer later (e.g. to change the PWM-value with `self.color.duty()`. My problem is, I don't know, how to create any kind of list of all created attributes, so I can iterate through them later on.
Thinking about something like:

```
for color in color_list:
    color.duty(number_gained_via_mqtt)
```

But how can I put the created attributes into this "color_list"?

**Update**

Thank you for the first Answers! The Problem is, a simple list of the keys does not solve my problem. I can't call self.key_from_list (as far as I know).

E.g. if I create a liste from keys `color_list=["r","g","b","w"]`I can't (or don't know how to) iterate through them.

```
for color in color_list:
    self.color.duty(0)
```

will not work, because the list only contains strings and I don't know, how to call attributes of my class with that name (if that makes any sense)

The full code looks like this:

```
class Stripe():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.on = 1
        self.leds = dict()
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, PWM(Pin(value)))
            self.leds[key] = 255
    
    def display(self):
        if self.on:
            for key in self.leds:
                self.key.duty(self.leds.get(key)) # does not work
        else:
            for key in self.leds:
                 self.key.duty(0) # does not work either
```

**Update 2 - Solved**

Thank you guys for the answers. Using a dictionary instead of attributes solves the problem.

Comment: can you please provide a more concrete example?

Comment: `list(kwargs.keys())`

Comment: Have you considered using a dictionary instead of attributes?

Comment: Of course it doesn't work, `key` is a string object, using `self.key` doesn't magically translate into executing the code `self.the_string`. You seem to understand you can use `setattr`, so in this case, you would use `getattr`, i.e. `getattr(self, key).duty(self.leds.get(key))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your colors are the keys of `kwargs`, which is a regular dictionary, you can do

```
self.color_list = list(kwargs.keys())
```

Then you can address them as

```
for color in self.color_list:
    getattr(self, color).duty(number_gained_via_mqtt)
```

If you just want a list of the PWM objects, you can do that too:

```
self.color_list = []
for color, pin in kwargs.items():
    pwm = PWM(Pin(pin))
    setattr(self, color, pwm)
    self.color_list.append(pwm)
```

Then you can do

```
for color in self.color_list:
    color.duty(number_gained_via_mqtt)
```

A better option might be to store everything into a dictionary rather than the instance `__dict__`, where all the attributes are mixed together:

```
self.colors = {color: PWM(Pin(pin)) for color, pin kwargs.items()}
```

Then you can access it much simpler:

```
for pin in self.colors.values():
    pin.duty(number_gained_via_mqtt)
```

Comment: That's definitely a good solution for my problem. Thank you! (I am still wondering if there is any way to address the attributes the way I tried but at least my code works now <3 )